# Frustrating Smarty Error : call to undefined function phperror_reporting

Tags: hosting, smarty

I am trying to upload my site onto the server but I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function phperror_reporting() in /home/jagani/public_html/theforum/forumfiles.php on line 1
```

First few lines of the file are:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

session_start();
```

Seems that the space between the php and error_reporting isn't being registered. I'd appreciate any insight on this problem.

Comment: Strange. What OS's are you on?

Comment: try placing `error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);` after `session_start();`

Comment: Tried the above: Here is the following error ---

Call to undefined function phpsession_start() 

The server is Linux CentOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it sounds like a problem with the whitespace. If you've got ssh access, I'd try creating a test php file by typing `vi test.php` and then putting the following code:

```
<?php

print("test");

?>
```

Try viewing that file and see if it works; if so, then your problem is an encoding issue, which you might be able to fix by running dos2unix on the affected file. Does it only affect that one file (and/or others) or is it any php file on the system?