# What's causing this (phperror_reporting)

Tags: php

here's the top of my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Even if I make 100 empty lines before the error_reporting(E_ALL); (or any other function), I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function phperror_reporting()
```

What's causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691837/frustrating-smarty-error-call-to-undefined-function-phperror-reporting

Comment: Thanks, I was using UTF-8 encoding in Notepad++. Fixed it with ANSI as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file encoding, Depending on the server it could be parsing line endings differently, namely, windows uses a CRLF line ending (`\r\n`) and linux/mac just uses a line feed (`\n`). Try switching your line ending delimiter (in your text editor that you were using to write the code) to CRLF because it will work correctly in both environments and see if that fixes the issue.